# Invalid Graphics State - ongoing issue for beginner RStudio/R user

Tags: graphics, warnings, rstudio

I am working on an assignment for a course. The code creates variables for use in a data.dist function from rms. We then create a simple linear regression model using ols(). Printing/creating the first plot before the data.dist() and ols() functions is simple. We use:

```
plot(x,y,pch='o') 
lines(x,yTrue,lty=2,lwd=.5,col='red')
```

Then we create the data.dist() and the ols(), here named fit0.

```
mydat=data.frame(x=x,y=y)
dd=datadist(mydat)
options(datadist='dd') 

fit0=ols(y~x,data=mydat)
fit0
anova(fit0)
```

This all works smoothly, printing out the results of the linear regression and the anova table. Then, we want to predict based on the model, and plot these predictions. The plot prints out nicely, however the lines and points won't show up here. The code:

```
ff=Predict(fit0)
plot(ff)
lines(x,yTrue,lwd=2,lty=1,col='red')
points(x,y,pch='.')
```

Note - this works fine in R. I much prefer to use RStudio, though can switch to R if there's no clear solution this issue. I've tried dev.off() several times (i.e. repeat until get, I've tried closing RStudio and re-opening, I've uninstalled and reinstalled R and RStudio, rms package (which includes ggplot2), updated the packages, made my RStudio graphics window larger. Any solution I've seen, doesn't work. Help!